# Python method using class variables, right approach

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a question about python using OOP. 
If I have two classes, and a method which takes variables from those classes, I pass the classes as parameters of the method as shown below. I am sure that this is not the right approach, and this is why I would like to know an alternative and more efficient way to do it. Specifically:

```
class Player(object):
    x_player = 5
    y_player = 5

class Food(object):
    x_food = 10
    y_food = 10

def method(Player, Food):
    if Player.x_player > Food.x_food:
        print('Food behind)
    if Player.x_player < Food.x_food:
        print('Food in front')
```

Is this correct? If I use the method `def __init(self)__` then I cannot pass those variables in the function.

Thank you

Comment: You probably need to go again through the OOP tutorial

Comment: Are you actually instantiating your classes anywhere? You appear to be using your classes themselves as objects. (Can't say for sure, since you don't show how you are calling `method`.)

Comment: you can accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I use the method def **init(self)** then I cannot pass those variables in the function.

This understanding is wrong, as you can add parameters to `__init__`.

How about this? Or you still insist to use class method? If you choose class method, your solution already ok, just call with `method(Player, Food)` or even you did not need the parameters added in the function.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x_player = x
        self.y_player = y

class Food(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x_food = x
        self.y_food = y

def method(player, food):
    if player.x_player > food.x_food:
        print('Food behind')
    if player.x_player < food.x_food:
        print('Food in front')

method(Player(5, 5), Food(10, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

if those are class variables, you can just refer to those variables as `classname.var_name`:

```
class A:
    a = 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(A.a)
```

if the values are defined by instance, then you need to instantiate the class variables and then you can perform comparison on that

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = A(5)
    y = A(10)
    print(x.a > y.a)

>> False
```

Also this is `python` and in python you don't specify the data types of function arguments so you can send any object and be carefree of which class' instance it is. You code should handle the exceptions if a wrong class' object is sent.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

def fun(obj):
    print(obj.a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = A(5)
    y = B(10)
    fun(x)
    fun(y)

>> 5
>> 10
```

---

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

def fun(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, B):
        print(obj.a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = A(5)
    y = B(10)
    fun(x)
    fun(y)

>> 5
```